# is is possible to call in pytest python tow init drivers

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, appium

I need to do a simple test in Python under class where I am starting with web driver and switch to mobile driver

I have conftest.py where I am going to init mobile and web driver using pytest.fixture(scope="session")
and other class which I have function which should switch between drivers

please advise if the example below is valid or if I need to separate it into different 2 functions with  @pytest.mark.usefixtures("...") one for mobile and the other for the web
you may see the code below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfKr1.png)

the code is in Python is below

```
import pytest
from appium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver as selenium_webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def mobile_driver():
    # Set up desired capabilities for the mobile device/emulator
    desired_caps = {
        'platformName': 'Android',
        'deviceName': 'YOUR_DEVICE_NAME',
        'appPackage': 'com.github.android',
        'appActivity': 'com.github.android.features.login.LoginActivity'
    }

    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def web_driver():
    # Set up the browser and driver
    options = selenium_webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
    driver = selenium_webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("mobile_driver", "web_driver")
def test_github_hybrid(mobile_driver, web_driver):
    # Mobile test
    mobile_driver.find_element_by_id("login_username").send_keys("your_username")
    mobile_driver.find_element_by_id("login_password").send_keys("your_password")
    mobile_driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()

    # Web test
    web_driver.get("https://github.com")
    search_input = WebDriverWait(web_driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']"))
    )
    search_input.send_keys("openai")
    search_input.submit()
```

Comment: Please post the code as text not screenshot.